# Problem connecting my domain to Nginx VPS

Tags: node.js, nginx, dns, vps

First of all im a beginner on deploying vps servers, my problem is that i buyed a domain in a external page and i want to connect it to my vps by nginx, when a run in the browser the server ip it works perfectly but when i try to run the domain it says "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN", and i have no idea of what to do, here is my dns configuration:
[dns config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0Ocd.png)

and here is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
   listen       80 default_server;
   listen       [::]:80 default_server;
   server_name  parquecanal.cl www.parquecanal.cl;

   location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
}
```

Comment: Im running a node js aplication with pm2

Comment: listening to port 3000